# Inserting parameters for a function as array

Tags: vba

I have the following two arrays:

```
Sub ArrayLoop(array1, array2)

 Dim Students() As Variant
 Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

 ENG1 = Array(423.5482, 425.6641, 425.6641)
 ENG2 = Array(224.0202, 222.5737, 222.5737)

 GER1 = Array(454.692, 454.0753, 454.0753)  
 GER2 = Array(220.8373, 222.2446, 224.3517)

 For i = 0 To 40

   x1 = parameter1(i)
   x2 = parameter2(i)

   y1 = parameter1(i + 1)
   y2 = parameter2(i + 1)

   With myDocument.Shapes.AddLine(BeginX:=x1, BeginY:=x2, EndX:=y1, EndY:=y2).Line
    .DashStyle = msoLineDashDotDot
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 0, 128)
   End With

  Next i
End Sub
```

What I basically want to do now is fire the macro "ArrayLoop" with two parameters and then that array should be used. S0

```
ArrayLoop(ENG1, ENG2)
```

Should work with the Array's ENG1 and ENG2

However when I do this

```
Call ArrayLoop(ENG1, ENG2)
```

I get an error 13 that says, the items are not comparable. Any thoughts on how I should get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ENG1` and `ENG2` need to be passed as *paramaters* to the sub. In your code, they are defined as local variables. When invoking a routine with parameters, these parameters need to be defined *elsewhere* and *passed* to the routine.

```
Sub ArrayLoop(array1, array2)
  Dim i As Long
  For i = LBound(array1) To UBound(array1) - 1
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddLine(BeginX:=array1(i), BeginY:=array2(i), EndX:=array1(i + 1), EndY:=array2(i + 1)).Line
      .DashStyle = msoLineDashDotDot
      .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 0, 128)
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```

Now here's how you define parameters and call the routine:

```
Sub TestArrayLoop()
  Dim ENG1, ENG2, GER1, GER2
  ENG1 = Array(423.5482, 425.6641, 425.6641)
  ENG2 = Array(224.0202, 222.5737, 222.5737)

  GER1 = Array(454.692, 454.0753, 454.0753)
  GER2 = Array(220.8373, 222.2446, 224.3517)

  ArrayLoop ENG1, ENG2  ' <----- invoke the routine and pass it the parameters
End Sub
```

Comment: Hm, this gives me a subscript is out of reach error at this line:  With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddLine(BeginX:=array1(i), BeginY:=array2(i), EndX:=array1(i + 1), EndY:=array2(i + 1)).Line
.. Any thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind the loop was going to 40 :). Thanks for your help!